# Is it possible to have a GLS model with Poisson errors?

Tags: generalized-least-squares

I understand that GLS is a method of estimation which accounts for structure in the error term. Does this structure refer to the distribution of the errors? If so, can we have a GLS model with Poisson errors?

Comment: What type of response variable do you have for your model? Is it a count response? If yes, why not use a Poisson regression model?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement ya it is a count response so I am using a Poisson regression model but I was just curious if there was another way

Answer (score 1):

GLS stands for "generalized least squares*. It doesn't consider the error distribution, it minimizes a particular least-squares type of quadratic criterion. It also relies on the variance-covariance matrix being known.

It could be used to deal with variance proportional to the mean (a *quasi-Poisson* type of variance structure), via reweighted least squares (estimate the model, update the variances, repeat), but not with taking any account of the fact that it's Poisson *per se*.